# How to remove CheckBox icon of DataTable in Flutter?

Tags: datatable, dart, flutter

I'm implementing a `DataTable` to show some data, to do this I'm using a `PaginatedDataTable`, so I can load and show my data, the problem is that my `DataTable` shows a **CheckBox** per row and I don't want it.

This is my current result:

[image]

I want remove these **CheckBox** but I not have idea how to do it.

**Code:**

```
ExpensesDataSource _expensesDataSource = ExpensesDataSource([expense]);

    Widget getDataTable() {
      return PaginatedDataTable(
        header: Text('Despesas', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF4C4C4C), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),),
        columns: <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
            label: Text("Data"),
            numeric: false,
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text("Descrição"),
            numeric: false,
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text("Total"),
            numeric: false,
          ),
        ],
        source: _expensesDataSource,
      );
  }


class ExpensesDataSource extends DataTableSource {

  List<Expense> _expenses = <Expense>[];
  int _selectedCount = 0;

  ExpensesDataSource(List<Expense> listExpenses) {
      this._expenses = listExpenses;
  }

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    final Expense expense = _expenses[index];
    return DataRow.byIndex(
        index: index,
        onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
          print('Row selected: $value ${expense.name}');
        },
        cells: [
          DataCell(Text(expense.date)),
          DataCell(Text(expense.name)),
          DataCell(Text(Utils.convert2currency(expense.total_amount)))
        ]
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement rowCount
  int get rowCount => _expenses.length;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _selectedCount;

}
```

Comment: I believe this link here should clear all your doubts.
[Flutter DataTable - Tap on row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58900780/6889637)

Answer (score 10):

> **UPDATE**
>
> Available now on Stable channel.

It's possible if you are on master channel not on stable channel.

You have to add only one property to `DataTable` which is `showCheckboxColumn` to be false.

Your full code after edit will be

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Sample",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
    body: Column(children: <Widget>[
      DataTable(
        showCheckboxColumn: false,
        sortAscending: true,
        columns: <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('Product name'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('Product Quantity'),
          ),
        ],
        rows: items
            .map(
              (itemRow) => DataRow(
                onSelectChanged: (bool selected) {
                  if (selected) {
                    //'row-selected: ${itemRow.index}'
                  }
                },
                cells: [
                  DataCell(
                    Text(itemRow.itemName),
                    showEditIcon: false,
                    placeholder: false,
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text(itemRow.itemQuantity),
                    showEditIcon: true,
                    placeholder: false,
                    //onTap: _getSelectedRowInfo,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      )
    ]),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ));
  }
}
```

Some flutter developer doesn't recommend change to master, but if no problem with you, you can change it using these commands:
`flutter channel master`
`flutter upgrade`

Comment: Available in stable channel as of Flutter 1.17

Comment: This will get rid of the check box from all rows.  I would like to figure out a way to get rid of the checkbox on a row by row basis.  Such as from the above image, row 1 should have the check box because there is data in there but rows 2 and greater shouldn't have a selection checkbox.

Comment: I think you should make your custmized one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add only one property to **DataTable** which is **showCheckboxColumn** to be false.

Your full code after the edit will be:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Sample",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
    body: Column(children: <Widget>[
      DataTable(
        showCheckboxColumn: false,
        sortAscending: true,
        columns: <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('Product name'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('Product Quantity'),
          ),
        ],
        rows: items
            .map(
              (itemRow) => DataRow(
                onSelectChanged: (bool selected) {
                  if (selected) {
                    //'row-selected: ${itemRow.index}'
                  }
                },
                cells: [
                  DataCell(
                    Text(itemRow.itemName),
                    showEditIcon: false,
                    placeholder: false,
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text(itemRow.itemQuantity),
                    showEditIcon: true,
                    placeholder: false,
                    //onTap: _getSelectedRowInfo,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      )
    ]),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently only by omitting `onSelectionChange: ...` or passing `null`
instead of

```
    onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
      print('Row selected: $value ${expense.name}');
    },
```

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DataRow/onSelectChanged.html

Comment: And if I want liste the selection?

Comment: Then there is currently no way to get rid of the checkbox as far as I know.

Comment: I can change the CheckBox for another Icon or put on other side of table?

Comment: As far as I know there is no other way to influence it except getting rid of it by not passing a selection changed handler. You could try to implement or extend `DataRow` and customize its behavior, but I don't know if this is possible. I'll reopen https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26211

Answer (score 0):

I delete these two of `selected:` and `onSelectChanged:` in `DataRow.byIndex()` and checkbox gone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **onSelectChanged** and **selected**  property from DataRow and add this on each data cell..

```
DataCell(
    Text(
       employee.lastName.toUpperCase(),
    ),
    onTap: () {
      print("Tapped " + employee.firstName);
      // do whatever you want
    },
),
```